# calloc struct in C

Tags: objective-c, c, memory, struct

I'm trying to initialize a pointer to a struct with 0.0 values in there. Look at the following situation:

```
typedef struct 
{
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
} structA;

structA *ptr = calloc(100000, sizeof(structA));
```

I want all the values in *ptr be structA with initial values of {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, but this is not I have now. Many of the indices of *ptr appear correctly, but some indices appear with weird values (like {0.0, 0.0, 10241256124.0}).

If I try malloc, the same thing happens.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you check the return value of `calloc` to insure that it succeeded? Is there any code running between the time you allocate the memory and the time you check it's contents? How sure are you that you are not scribbling on the block?

Comment: How are you checking the contents of `ptr` to find these strange values?

Comment: Assuming you run a loop immediately after the calloc to check for non-zero, if you memset the allocated data to zero and check again, does it still fail?

Comment: How could I check??? using "printf" with "%f %f %f", of course!!! I'm checking it right after calloc. Checking individually (ptr[287]) or inside a "for loop", always I see that problem on some indices...

Comment: Well, obviously if I manually set each value to 0.0 inside a "for loop" after the calloc it'll work fine. But I want to know why calloc is not working as it should be. Doesn't calloc work for values inside my "structA"?

Comment: Maybe you could include the code for your `printf` loop instead of being overly dramatic with your punctuation. And here's the [`calloc` man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/calloc.html), `calloc` sets all the bits in the allocated memory to zero. You could have been checking what's in `ptr` using a debugger so asking how you know that `ptr` is messed up is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: You should be able to give a trivial minimal program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: if i a create a blank command line project in xcode and loop the 100000 structs, all of them have correcly zeroed fields.The loop is use to print out is `for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        NSLog(@"index %i values %f,%f,%f", i, ptr->a, ptr->b, ptr->c);
        ptr++;
    }`

Comment: You say that when you try `malloc()` the same thing happens.  Is the ratio of zeroed to non-zeroed items about the same?  Could your code base have a macro definition overriding the function call for `calloc()` hiding somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You're doing something wrong...  I've never used objective-c, so I stuck the code below into [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5x3kN) and it worked as expected... (printing out done, not failed because) all values were zero'd.  My guess is you're not checking properly, since it's quite unlikely there's a bug in your compiler...

```
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct 
{
    float a;
        float b;
        float c;
} structA;



int main() {
    int count = 100000;
    int i;
    structA *ptr = calloc(count, sizeof(structA));
    if(ptr) {
        for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
            if(ptr[i].a || ptr[i].b || ptr[i].c) {
                printf("fail\n");
            }
        }
        printf("done\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```